# Octave and MatConvNet integration

Tags: octave, matconvnet

Does anyone ever succeeded in installing MAtConvNet under Octave ?
If so could you please let me know the steps to proceed ?

thanks and regards

Arno

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking into this issue myself. I have reached a point in researching this where I feel the issues are too complicated for my own project and are not worth my time trying to finish running down. However, if someone else is determined to track this down, hopefully this information will help.

The basic problem comes down Octave only compiling to support 32-bit architectures even if you use the 64-bit installer. If you want Octave to support 64-bit, you need to compile from source using the appropriate compiling options. The other details are as follows.

MatConvNet appears to require a 64-bit system to compile.

http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_compilenn/

MatConvNet detects system architecture in in the `mex_cuda_config` function in `vl_compilenn.m`:

https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/matlab/vl_compilenn.m

Octave's `computer` function is not a perfect analog to Matlab's function, so the `mex_cuda_config` function in `vl_compilenn.m` would need to be modified or Octave's `computer` function would need to be updated. More specifically, the `computer` function's handling of the `'arch'` argument needs to be changed.

There may be other issues, but this is where I would start if I had the time to invest in trying to track this down.

Comment: Hi FirstPrime, Thank you for your investigation. I think indeed this is a good start. On my side, I switched to Matlab in order to run my tests and I have no time currently to look at this issue. I might come back to this in a few month if my planning allow it.